# LogCat error spamming: old mainboard version

Tags: android, version, sensors

[This error adds to my LogCat view for android many times a second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8E5Rw.png)!

It occurs when I run my application from eclipse on my ZTE blade android 2.2. It does not matter what application I run by the way.

Anyone know how I should find out how to solve this problem or actually knows what's wrong?

Comment: Not sure how to fix, but you can suppress it with `adb logcat Sensors:S *:D`